# Insight with ending a loop by pressing the enter key in Java

Tags: java, loops, key, enter

I am in a low level java programming class, and I am having trouble figuring something my professor assigned to us. We originally made a program that added integers that were placed in an arraylist. She then asked us to make it as user friendly as possible, without having a specific amount of integers the user inputs. So I came up with this:

```
public class CalculatorREDONE 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

         ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

         System.out.println("Enter any numbers you would like to add. ");
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


         do
         {
            numbers.add((int) input.nextInt()); //inserting input into the arraylist
            System.out.println("The sum is " + sum(numbers)); //test output
         }while(input.hasNextInt()); // I believe this needs to change but I am unsure what it should be
                System.out.println(sum(numbers)); 
    //My Problem here is that the loop doesn't end, therefore cannot print this output


            input.close();


}

public static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> list)
{
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        total += list.get(i);
    }

    return total;
}


}
```

Sorry for the clutter of comments, I'm trying to show any of you my mindset behind what I did. Thank you so much in advance for anyone that has any suggestions!

Comment: do you have a specific question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, I guess my question is, how can I get the do-while loop to stop looping by the user pressing enter? When the user presses the Enter key, it outputs the sum, but it does not leave the loop. The user can keep entering integers and the loop keeps adding them to the array therefore adding them to the sum.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps where in you take an input from user to terminate the program.

```
public class CalculatorREDONE {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("Enter any numbers you would like to add or -1 to exit");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  //  boolean nextAvailable = true;
    while(true) 
    {
        String nextVal = input.nextLine();
        if(nextVal.isEmpty()) {
           break;
        }
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(nextVal)); //inserting input into the arraylist

      //  System.out.println("The sum is " + sum(numbers)); //test output
    } //while (!input.next().); // I believe this needs to change but I am unsure what it should be
    System.out.println(sum(numbers));
    //My Problem here is that the loop doesn't end, therefore cannot print this output


    input.close();


}

public static int sum(List<Integer> list) {
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        total += list.get(i);
    }

    return total;
}
```

}

Comment: Although this WOULD in fact help, I was wondering if it were possible to make it easier for the user. Rather than typing a negative number, they could just press enter. I sort of got it to work, but the loop wont end. The user can just keep entering values. Thank you though! If I can't get it another way, I will definitely do this!

Comment: I have modified the answer to check for the input. However, since the line is being read you may need to include a regex to validate the input for Integer values only or there is no NumberFormatException.

Comment: I don't know if I am supposed to go that in depth with this, being that I don't even know what some of that means. Thank you for your suggestions and help though! I tried it anyway, and I had an error not within the code, but with Eclipse itself, "Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again." I appreciate the suggestion though! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this -- it takes the input as a string, checks the length. If the user just hits enter the length will not be greater than zero. This catches the number exception from the parseInt by confirming the user has ended their list.

Note that I didn't include your sum portion since it wasn't relevant to the question of breaking the loop. You'll need to re-add

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CalculatorREDONE 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("Enter any numbers you would like to add. ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userinput = "xx";
    int nextnum = 0;
    while (userinput.length() > 0) {
        try {
            userinput = input.nextLine();
            nextnum = Integer.parseInt(userinput);
            numbers.add(nextnum); 
            System.out.println("Taken"); 
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Inputs complete");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(numbers); 

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I put "Taken" in there just so the user (or me for testing) would confirm the number was added to the list. It can be removed or replaced with a different message. Same with "Inputs Complete" which will come up the first time the user just hits enter. I should note that this won't stop the list if the user puts in something like "end" it'll just repeat "Inputs Complete"

Comment: This is close to what I am trying to do, I think I can work off of this code. Thank you!

Comment: I would just like to say that, after I realized what you had it doing, you hit the nail on the head. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, good luck adapting it to your needs, maybe include some instructions to the user to "hit enter on a blank line to end" or something when you add your math back in and you should be in good shape.